# How to show splash screen only when the app starts "fresh"?

Tags: java, android, xml, splash-screen

I want to show the splash screen only once during the Application life cycle. Here is my code:

SplashScreenActivity.java:

```
final int welcomeScreenDisplay = 3000;

Thread welcomeThread = new Thread() {

    int wait = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            super.run();

            while (wait < welcomeScreenDisplay) {
                sleep(1000);
                wait += 1000;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("EXc=" + e);
        } finally {

            // Start other Activity
            startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,
                    MainActiviey.class));
            finish();
        }
    }
};
welcomeThread.start();
```

Manifest:

```
    <activity android:name=".SplashScreenActivity" android:label="test"
    android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActiviey" android:label="test"
         android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The problem is if I press the hardware HOME botton to hide the app and open the App again at the application list. It will show the splash screen again (instead of showing the `MainActivity`).
Is it possible to show splash screen only when the app starts "fresh" (not show at onresume() )? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to store a flag, that would indicate that your splash has already been shown. Check it in `onCreate()` method of your splash screen and if it is present, launch the next activity.

Comment: But then he has to make sure to unset the flag when the app terminates, which isn't always possible to control...

Comment: I thought that by 'Application Lifecycle' author meant that splash screen must be shown only once, right after the installation. It is hard to determine when app terminates, true. But showing splash screen again after that would provide a bad user experience. User doesn't know when Android decides to terminate the application, from his persective this splash screen would appear pretty randomly. Wouldn't it be annoying?

Comment: I agree with you that splash screens are often annoying and unnecessary (unless they're masking some necessary background loading). Unfortunately, in this case I think the asker meant the usual practice of showing the splash screen every time the app starts "fresh" (i.e. not being resumed).

Comment: LouieGeetoo is right. I want the splash screen show ONCE when every time the app starts "fresh"

Comment: I don't see why you'd want to do it, but anyway... You may try to use [Activity.onSaveInstanceState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)): keep the `isShown` flag in an instance of your Activity and save in `onSaveInstanceState()`. Theoretically, it should do the trick.

Comment: Be aware thought, that this is a bad approach and you should have a very good reasons to justify it. This whole 'application start' concept is quite alien to Android. We faced similar issue when implemented run counter.

Comment: Thanks Ash.It is because Samsung rejected my App because of this reason.

Answer (score 6):

You can't have this intent for two activities:

```
  <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Also you might want to hide the splash screen from the history stack in case you decided launch another activity inside it as per Ash suggestion.

You can use this flag on your activity tag:

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

Comment: Thanks khr2003. They are not the same. The intent-filter of .SplashScreenActivity is 'android.intent.category.LAUNCHER' and the intent-filter of .MainActiviey is 'android.intent.category.DEFAUL'. android:noHistory="true" is not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Handler handler;
private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 2000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    SplashStart();

}

private void SplashStart() {
    handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    }
}
```