# on back press splash screen showing instead of last opened screen

Tags: android, onbackpressed

I am making one android application. When i open the app splash screen showing and then it goes to mainactivity. now if user will press the back button and open the app from minimize button. it shows splash again instead of mainactivity. can any one help me to solve this? following is the code of splash activity please check and give solution.

Splash

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                fcm_id = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
                session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

                usermyid=session.userID();
                if(usermyid!=null)
                {
                    System.out.println("usermyid is not null"+usermyid);
                    usermyid=session.userID();
                    userd=Long.parseLong(usermyid);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("usermyid is  null"+usermyid);
                    android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
                            Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
                    System.out.println("Without Exclude alphabets"+android_id);

                    android_id = android_id.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
                    System.out.println("After Exclude alphabets"+android_id);
                    long x=Long.parseLong(android_id);
                    x*=-1;

                    System.out.println("Final Id" + x);
                    session_id = String.valueOf(x);
                    System.out.println("sessionid in skipactivity" + session_id);
                    session.createLoginSession(session_id);
                    userd=Long.parseLong(session_id);
                }


                if (session.checkLogin()) {


                    if(userd < 0)
                    {
                        System.out.println("It is minus"+userd);

                        prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPrefSKIP", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        boolean rb0 = prefs.getBoolean("skipstuff", false);
                        if(rb0 == true){
                            // Do something
                            System.out.println("SKIP IS TRUE");
                            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                            userid = session.userID();
                            username=session.username();
                            userlastname=session.userlastname();
                            useradd1=session.useradd1();
                            useradd2=session.useradd2();
                            usercity=session.usercity();
                            userstate=session.userstate();
                            userzip=session.userpincode();
                            usercountry=session.usercountry();
                            userphone=session.userphone();
                            usermail=session.useremail();
                            usercounter=session.usercounter();


                            System.out.println("User ID in MAIN : " + userid+username+userlastname+useradd1+useradd2+usercity+userstate+userzip+usercountry);
                            i.putExtra("id", userid);
                            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            startActivity(i);
                            finish();

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("SKIP IS FALSE");
                            //  String forskipid= String.valueOf(userd);
                            Intent menuLeft = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, SkipActivity.class);
                            //menuLeft.putExtra("id",session_id);
                            startActivity(menuLeft);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("It is plus"+userd);
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        userid = session.userID();
                        username=session.username();
                        userlastname=session.userlastname();
                        useradd1=session.useradd1();
                        useradd2=session.useradd2();
                        usercity=session.usercity();
                        userstate=session.userstate();
                        userzip=session.userpincode();
                        usercountry=session.usercountry();
                        userphone=session.userphone();
                        usermail=session.useremail();
                        usercounter=session.usercounter();


                        System.out.println("User ID in MAIN : " + userid+username+userlastname+useradd1+useradd2+usercity+userstate+userzip+usercountry);
                        i.putExtra("id", userid);
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                    }


                } else {


                    System.out.println("THIS SHOULD NOT BE SHOW");

                }

                //GetNotification();
                AddDeviceToken();
                SplashActivity.this.finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);

    }
```

MainActivity

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {


        if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()>1){
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }else
        if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()==0){
            this.finish();
        }
    }


@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        viewtocart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        super.onStart();
    }
```

Comment: post the code..

Comment: code of what? splash or mainactivity

Comment: Splash screen..

Comment: So, what do you want to do? When You open from minimize, It should show MainActivity? - Then, When you start calling MainActivity via Intent, put finish(); there below startActivity(i).

Comment: i already did finish

Comment: where to put?he has no code nly

Comment: chris post main activity and splash

Comment: what is SkipActivity?post main also

Comment: i posted main..skip is the activity which i launch for first time user..if user will click on button of skipactivity then user can acess the app without the login.

Comment: Don't finish() after startActivity(i); & also do not use addflags() try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually in the method onBackPress user should not override it.It is usually maintained by the android system to to finish activities.Change your onBackPressed() method like this and check is it helps you.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0 &&
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.your_container)!=null) {

        Fragment fragment= getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.your_container);
        if(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase(FragmentTest.class.getSimpleName())){
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
        }

    }else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
```

**EDIT**:

**back button and open the app from minimize button**

The problem is here.Since you have started the activity splash first and then while going to main you are clearing flag and finishing splash.So the back stack contains only one activity.

When you press the back button in the main activity the app gets quit instead of showing any backstacked activities.Here in mainactivity when you press back the lifecycle method onPause(),onStop() and onDestroy() are called.

The reason the splash gets called again when you open the app again from recent is that the app is started again and splash is the first activity. Hence it is shown.

Pressing the back Button in home activity quits the apps,but pressing the home button minimises your app. Minimised app opens the app from where you left it since it will be in memory.

To know more about activity lifecycles check this link https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

Comment: check the edit.The problem is not with your code.This is the usual life cycle of android.Pressing the back in home will quit app since you are clearing stack and going to home activity.When the app quits also it wil stay minimized in recent app list until you clear the recent apps list.Instead if you press the home button on your devic and open the app The splash screen wont come because app is minimised.

Comment: you are right..but the thing which i need is possible or not?

Comment: what you want to do?

Comment: close the app using on back press and open app again from minimized and load the mainactivity or previously opened screen instaed of splash

Comment: you need to save data in Sharedpreference to do that.You have to save the user data or session in shared preference and every time you open app you need to check if data is saved in preference.If saved skip splash screen else show splash screen.Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682439/how-to-show-splash-screen-only-when-the-app-starts-fresh and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18612824/how-to-run-an-activity-only-once-like-splash-screen

Comment: can you help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46764155/how-to-access-arraylist-of-arraylist-in-adapters

Answer (score 2):

In your SplashActivity,
add finish() when you are about to fire Intent for mainActivity.

In your MainActivity,implement onBackPresssed(),onDestroy() and onResume();

Hope this will help.

Comment: post MainActivity Code.

Comment: posted sir..please check

Comment: in onresume what to do sir?

Comment: Just add super.onBackPress() in ur onBackpress() and comment other line of code in onBackPrESS()

Comment: @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {

    super.onBackPressed();
}