# How to access arraylist of arraylist in adapters

Tags: android, arraylist, baseadapter, jsonparser

Hi i am making android application. I am using json parsing in my application. first of all this is my json response

```
{
  "Data": {
    "headerText": "Revolution",
    "productStartingPrice": "$38.78",

    "sizeList": [
      {
        "textUpper": "Revolution for (Pink)",
        "textLower": "$38.78",
        "packList": [
          {
            "textUpper": "3 DOSES",
            "textLower": "$38.78",

          }
          {
            "textUpper": "6 DOSES",
            "textLower": "$71.60",

          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "textUpper": "Revolution for (Blue)",
        "textLower": "$46.92",
        "packList": [
          {
            "textUpper": "3 DOSES",
            "textLower": "$46.92",
          }
          {
            "textUpper": "6 DOSES",
            "textLower": "$79.56",


          }
          {
            "textUpper": "12 DOSES",
            "textLower": "$137.27",

          }
        ]
      }
    ]

  },
  "Status": 1,
  "Message": "",
  "UserMessage": ""
}
```

Now I am using custom alert dialog to load sizelist array and another dailog for packlist array. Now what i want is when user select (Pink) from sizelist then in second dailog i want to display 3 doses and 6 doses from packlist and when user select (Blue) i want to display 3 doses, 6 doses ,12 doses. Right now i am getting only last two items of (Blue) 6 doses ,12 doses. can any one help me to solve this?

```
 private void showDialog(){

        dialogf = new Dialog(getActivity());

        View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_main, null);

        ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.custom_list);
        Button close_btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.close_btn_sizelist);
        sizeadapter = new CustomListAdapterSize(getActivity(), sizelists);
        lv.setAdapter(sizeadapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            }
        });

        dialogf.setContentView(view);

        dialogf.show();
        close_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialogf.dismiss();
            }
        });


    }

    private void showDialogpacks(){

        dialogfpacks = new Dialog(getActivity());

        View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_main_packs, null);
        ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.custom_list_packs);
        Button close_btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.close_btn_packlist);

        adapterpacks = new CustomListAdaptertwo(getActivity(), sizelists);
        lv.setAdapter(adapterpacks);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            }
        });

        dialogfpacks.setContentView(view);
        dialogfpacks.show();



    }
 public class CustomListAdapterSize extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context context;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private List<ProductLandingSizeListModel> adaptersizelist;
        private CheckBox selected =null;
        private RadioButton mSelectedRB;
        public CustomListAdapterSize(Context context,List<ProductLandingSizeListModel> movieItems) {
            this.context = context;
            this.adaptersizelist=movieItems;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return adaptersizelist.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return adaptersizelist.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.listitem_productsizes, null);
                holder.txtproname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtproductsizenames);
                holder.txtproprice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtproductsizeprice);
                holder.radioBtn = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.productsize_radio);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            final ProductLandingSizeListModel m = adaptersizelist.get(position);
            holder.txtproname.setText(m.getSizeList_textUpper());
            holder.txtproprice.setText(m.getSizeList_textLower());

            if (position == mSelectedPosition ) {
                if (selected == null) {
                    holder.radioBtn.setChecked(true);
                    selected = holder.radioBtn;
                }
            }
            if (position == mSelectedPosition )
                holder.radioBtn.setChecked(true);
            else
                holder.radioBtn.setChecked(false);

            holder.radioBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    if (selected != null) {
                        selected.setChecked(false);
                    }
                    mSelectedPosition =position;
                    if(mSelectedPositionpack!=0)
                    {
                        mSelectedPositionpack=0;
                    }
                    holder.radioBtn.setChecked(true);
                    selected = holder.radioBtn;

                    notifyDataSetChanged();

                    dialogf.dismiss();
                    showDialogpacks();
                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }
        class ViewHolder{

            TextView txtproname,txtproprice;
            public CheckBox radioBtn;
        }

    }

    public class CustomListAdaptertwo extends BaseAdapter {


        private CheckBox selected =null;
        private Context context;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private List<ProductLandingSizeListModel> adaptersizelist;


        public CustomListAdaptertwo(Context context,List<ProductLandingSizeListModel> adaptersizelist) {
            this.context = context;
            this.adaptersizelist=adaptersizelist;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            if (adaptersizelist != null) {
                return adaptersizelist.size();
            }
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return adaptersizelist.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinnertwo, null);
                holder.txtproname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_main_seentwo);
                holder.txtproprice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sub_text_seentwo);
                holder.checkpack = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.productpack_radio);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            final ProductLandingSizeListModel m = adaptersizelist.get(position);

            for(int i=0;i<adaptersizelist.get(position).getPacklistmodel().size();i++)
            {
                System.out.println("PACK na data"+adaptersizelist.get(position).getPacklistmodel().get(i).getPackList_textUpper());

                holder.txtproname.setText(adaptersizelist.get(position).getPacklistmodel().get(i).getPackList_textUpper());
                holder.txtproprice.setText(adaptersizelist.get(position).getPacklistmodel().get(i).getPackList_textLower());

            }


            if (position == mSelectedPositionpack ) {
                if (selected == null) {
                    holder.checkpack.setChecked(true);
                    selected = holder.checkpack;
                }
            }
            if (position == mSelectedPositionpack )
                holder.checkpack.setChecked(true);
            else
                holder.checkpack.setChecked(false);

            holder.checkpack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    if (selected != null) {
                        selected.setChecked(false);
                    }
                    mSelectedPositionpack =position;
                    holder.checkpack.setChecked(true);
                    selected = holder.checkpack;
                   // selected_pack_text.setText(movieItems.get(position)+" - "+"$"+packItems.get(position));
                    notifyDataSetChanged();



                    dialogfpacks.dismiss();
                }
            });
            return convertView;
        }
        class ViewHolder{

            TextView txtproname,txtproprice;
            CheckBox checkpack;
        }

    }
```

Comment: you need to have a arraylist of packlist type in your sizelist modal class

Comment: yes i have already

Comment: @VivekMishra can you help

Comment: can you highlight the code where you are selecting from first list

Comment: check my adapters..please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your showDialogpacks like this.On click of the first dialog pass the position that is been clicked and then inside that pass only the item 
inside sizelists for particular position.

```
  private void showDialogpacks(int position){

    dialogfpacks = new Dialog(getActivity());

    View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_main_packs, null);
    ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.custom_list_packs);
    Button close_btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.close_btn_packlist);

    adapterpacks = new CustomListAdaptertwo(getActivity(), sizelists.get(position).getPacklistmodel());
    lv.setAdapter(adapterpacks);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }
    });

    dialogfpacks.setContentView(view);
    dialogfpacks.show();



}
```

Also change the second adapter list type to  `ProductLandingPackListModel`.

```
  public CustomListAdaptertwo(Context context,List<ProductLandingPackListModel> adaptersizelist) {
        this.context = context;
        this.adaptersizelist=adaptersizelist;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
```

And in the inside of the CustomAdapdtertwo getView method

```
    final ProductLandingPackListModel model = adaptersizelist.get(position);

    holder.txtproname.setText(model.getPackList_textUpper());
    holder.txtproprice.setText(model.getPackList_textLower());
```

Comment: its giving error (getActivity(), sizelists.get(position)); here. in second adapter do i need to change?

Comment: bro the problem is here in second adapter  get count.You need to pass single inner array item.  pass sizelists.get(position).packList.

Comment: I duno your method name..you need to pass like that and also change arrayList inside second adapter. It should be List<YOURPACKETLISTMODEL> adaptersizelist

Comment: show your data model also.Check that update.You have to pass getPacklistmodel().Also you need to change the list type in the second adapter to that of getPacklistmodel()

Comment: bro i change that method as per answer, its still giving red line

Comment: where see the error?I think this is it..this should solve your problem.

Comment: yeah its gone..now can you tell me that do i need that for loop in second adapter or not? and please tell me that how to call this method showDialogpacks();

Comment: and please tell me that how to call this method showDialogpacks(what should be here);

Comment: pass the clicked position from the first list

Comment: i have issue on first time click. its view as well

 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.product_view_sizes:
                showDialog();
                break;
            case R.id.product_view_packs:
                showDialogpacks();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

Comment: what problem?now is the issue solved?pass the position  like this         showDialogpacks(position);

Comment: You have call the method inside onItemClick also...with the position.It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Chris based upon size selection set packlist...update pack list of every size user selects

Comment: your second adapter should be of type ArrayList<Packs> and in sizelist on click set like below showDialogPacks(ArrayList<Packs>  packList) , set it to recyclerview

Comment: lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ArrayList<Packs> packList = sizeList.get(position).getPackList();        
           //now show dialog with above list
            }
        });

Comment: checkbox things you can handle  in adapter, on selection store that position